# What is the purpose of XOR with zero

Tags: php

Taken from here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#105414

```
function rome($N){ 
    $c='IVXLCDM'; 
    for($a=5,$b=$s='';$N;$b++,$a^=7) 
        for($o=$N%$a,$N=$N/$a^0;$o--;$s=$c[$o>2?$b+$N-($N&=-2)+$o=1:$b].$s); 
    return $s; 
}
```

What is the purpose of XOR `$a^0;` here? (4th line)

Deleting it doesn't seem to make any difference. Check it out at: http://goo.gl/K6TwQI

Comment: I don't think this function was designed to be understandable.

Comment: Nonetheless the XOR has to do something there...

Comment: It's most likely implicitly converting the expression to an integer, as XOR is a pretty fast operation.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst fair enough; this should be an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll commonly see people use bitwise operators to implicitly convert expressions to an integer because of the way the underlying language works. This is mainly because these operations are blazing fast and avoid function calls, etc.

Because XOR doesn't affect the integer part of the variable, my best best is that this is just being used to ensure `$a` is always evaluated as an integer.

Here's an [example](http://ideone.com/rkhSsL).

Comment: `$N` is always evaluated as an integer. or `$N/$a` _Order of operations_

Comment: But `$a` is always an integer. The XOR is applied to the whole expression (division before bitwise)